# Drawing the d'Alembert solution integral to the pde wave equation.

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

When solving the partial differential wave equation in 1 dimension along the x-axis, I use d'Alemberts formula to arrive at the following solution

$$u(x,t)=\frac{10}{6}\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct} ( \theta(y-1.9) - \theta(y-2.1) ) - ( \theta(y+2.1) - \theta(y+1.9))dy$$

I am supposed to draw this solution with $c=3$ and $t=1$ and I am unsure how to do this. Do I need to evaluate the integral? What would be the primitive function of the integrand?